# Exporting clipping mask from Illustrator to use in PowerPoint

Tags: adobe-illustrator, microsoft-powerpoint, clipping-mask

I have used a clipping mask in Illustrator on a vector object. When I export as EMF and import in to PowerPoint the mask got released.

Is there any way to export from Illustrator and retain the clipping mask to use in PowerPoint?

Comment: Powerpoint's datamodel does not.have clipping masks as far as im aware of so it will not work

Answer (score 1):

Clipping masks don't work outside of Illustrator. Use your illustration as a transparent PNG instead.

Answer (score 1):

Expand and flatten the clipping mask in Illustrator. Then save.

For Powerpoint, the WMF or EMF files needs to be *as simple as possible*. Or save as a PNG in Illustrator and use that in Powerpoint since Microsoft apps *really* prefer RGB raster files.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Pathfinder Divide prior to export.**

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer expand to explain how that solves it? that's a very short answer as it is.